# What happens when we create instance of Integer class in java

Tags: java, object

I have a confusion regarding the following code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    private int x;
    public HelloWorld(int x) {
       this.x = x;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       HelloWorld o1 = new HelloWorld(5);
       HelloWorld o2 = new HelloWorld(5);
       System.out.println(o1);
       System.out.println(o2);
       Integer i = new Integer(1);
       Integer j = new Integer(10);
       System.out.println(i);
       System.out.println(j);
    } 
}
```

Clearly, I made two objects of HelloWorld class and two objects of Integer class. When I print them the output is like:

```
HelloWorld@6d06d69c
HelloWorld@7852e922
1
10
```

My doubt is when I created Object of helloWorld class the objects store some references but when I create instance of Integer class, the values are stored in objects. Why is this happening.

Is there a way to directly store values in HelloWorld class objects also.

I have also noticed that whenever I create objects for any inbuilt class in java like String, Character, List, Map... they all store values. So what is that present additionally in these inbuilt classes.

Comment: Hint - try to add a `public String toString()` method to your `HelloWorld` class.

Comment: *Constructors for Strings, BigInteger, BigDecimal and the objects used to wrap primitives should never be used. Doing so is less clear and uses more memory than simply using the desired value in the case of strings, and using valueOf for everything else. Further, these constructors are deprecated in Java 9, which is an indication that they will eventually be removed from the language altogether.* See [S2129](https://sonarcloud.io/organizations/default/rules?open=squid%3AS2129&rule_key=squid%3AS2129).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My doubt is when I created Object of helloWorld class the objects store some references but when I create instance of Integer class, the values are stored in objects.

No, the value is being stored as a field within the instance (of `HelloWorld` or `Integer`) in both cases.

> Is there a way to directly store values in HelloWorld class objects also.

That's what your code does.

If you want to change how instances of your `HelloWorld` class are converted to string, override `toString`. For instance:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(this.x);
}
```

The output you're seeing now is the output of the default [`toString` from `Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#toString()).

Comment: Crowder, I understood that every object stores data in form of feilds within it, but why do i need to use " obj1.x " to access feild values in case of HelloWorld object whereas in case of Integer object I can access value without using any dot operator and field name.

Comment: @KKARTHIKEYAREDDY - Because the wrapper classes for primitives are special, and the language specification defines [unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) for them (and also [boxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)). Boxing and unboxing are specific to the class wrappers for primitives. See [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) or any good beginning Java book.

Comment: @KKARTHIKEYAREDDY - Note that the third paragraph of [your accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57073750/157247) is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Java's compiler supports autoboxing and unboxing for primitives and wrapper classes.

You can read about it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/autoboxing-unboxing-java/).

In your example, method `println` expects `int`, which is primitive. So compiler automatically unboxes it from `Integer`.

Comment: [`println`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object)) accepts an `Object`, which `Integer` already is without being unboxed.

Comment: ^^ the reason the OP sees the output they see is that `println(Object)` is used, and `toString` on the primitive classes output the primitive (converted to string), not because `println(int)` is used.